# How to convert date string to milliseconds in mac os shell?

Tags: shell, date, macos

I have the following date string `2020-01-17T06:41:48.000Z`.

I would like to convert it to such as `15810232300` which is milliseconds type in mac os shell.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Your example number value isn't milliseconds; you need two more digits for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can install coreutils which contains GNU date :

```
brew install coreutils
```

then

```
$ gdate -d "2020-01-17T06:41:48.000Z" +%s%3N
1579243308000
```

Answer (score 1):

With the BSD date supplied in OSX, you can

```bsh
timestring="2020-01-17T06:41:48.456Z"
/bin/date -jf "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S" "${timestring%.???Z}" "+%s${timestring: -4:3}"
```

```
1579261308456
```